# How can I pass data from the model to the view controller after loading a connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on login functionality for an app at the moment and I receive a dictionary from the server after connecting. I receive the dictionary in the function 
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
which I have in my model. With the dictionary info received from this, I then want to send that dictionary to the view controller, but the function has already returned by the time connectionDidFinishLoading completes.

How can I pass the data back to the view controller?

Comment: Use delegated methods.

Comment: @NekakKinich which delegated methods do you recommend? I'm new to iOS and I'm not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set teh delegate and implement the callback methods

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:theURL];
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    [urlConnection start];
```

The [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/) are

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [_detailsResponse setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_detailsResponse appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Do what you want with the data here.
}
```

Comment: I have already done this and I'm trying to figure out how to send the data I get from the model (where I'm doing all this) back to the view controller

Comment: @MichaelCrowley your NSURLConnectionDelegate SHOULD NOT be the model. The request should be made by the controller. What you do with the data received, is the model logic. You have it backwards